# Dynamically create dataframes in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala and spark. I have a requirement to create the dataframes dynamically by reading a file. each line of a file is a query. at last join all dataframes and store the result in a file.

I wrote below basic code, having trouble to dynamically create the dataframes.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf
import scala.io.Source

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val empFile = "/user/sri/sample2.txt"
sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> empFile, "header" -> "true")).registerTempTable("emp")

var cnt=0;
val filename ="emp.sql"
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines)
{
        println(line)
cnt += 1
//var dis: String  = "emp"+cnt
val  "emp"+cnt = sqlContext.sql("SELECT \"totalcount\", count(*) FROM emp")
println(dis)

//val  dis = sqlContext.sql("SELECT \"totalcount\", count(*) FROM emp")
}

println(cnt)
exit
```

Please help me, suggest me if it can be done better way

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? I assume you're code won't compile, considering this line:

> val  "emp"+cnt = sqlContext.sql("SELECT \"totalcount\", count(*) FROM emp")

In Scala, defining the *name* of some construct (`val "emp"+cnt` in your case) programatically is not easily possible.

In your case, you could use a collection to hold the results.

```
val queries = for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) yield {
  sqlContext.sql("SELECT \"totalcount\", count(*) FROM emp")
}
val cnt = queries.length
```